# Can too many git branches slow down my Rails install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Had a really bad problem crop up recently. My Rails (3.2.12) started serving assets really slowly. Unmodified assets were taking a full second to return 304's. Total page loads were about 20 seconds:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - 13.5556
"GET /application.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.8758
"GET /bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 1.5164
"GET /printing.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.8421
"GET /application.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1335651
```

Historically, the app was never this slow.

Subsequent reloads of the same asset would still take over half a second

```
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 200 785 1.0668
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.6074
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.5951
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.6449
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.6031
```

A few weird things about the problem:

- None of my co-workers experienced the issue. We have a few devs working on this codebase and nobody has this problem. (So it isn't a problem with something in the code)
- Our Rails App codebase includes the source of an engine. Other apps share that engine. When the other apps point to the source of the engine, they aren't slow.

So I tried everything starting with the easiest and getting harder:

- Turn on/off asset pipeline, asset debugging, etc...
- git bisect back to June
- Take everything possible out of Gemfile
- Upgrade from Ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3
- Rebuild all gems
- Rebuild Ruby 1.9.3
- Uninstall and re-install rvm
- Rebuild Ruby 1.9.3 with optimizations

Nothing worked. Everything was slow.

Finally I blew away my project directory and re-cloned the app. I ran it and the assets served in reasonable time.

```
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2267 0.2029
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.1827
"GET /pages/logo-white-topbar.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.1822
```

I mean, we're not lighting the world on fire here but that's a dramatic improvement. Page loads went from 20s to 4s.

The only thing different about my old dir and the new cloned dir is that I have 69 git branches in the old dir. I should clean them out, obviously. Most are fully merged but some are just long-running feature branches.

My questions are: Is this a legitimate problem? Does having 70 branches really crush asset pipeline performance? Why is that? Is my .git crufty somehow? I clearly don't know enough about git to get a handle on this.

This is git 1.8.1.2 on OSX 10.8.4

Thanks.

**Update**: Rein's suggestion that git was a red herring had me snooping for other culprits. Turns out my log directory had swelled to immense size. I blew that away but it didn't make any difference. It's absurd that external assets (from mixpanel, for example) are being served in 24ms but my local machine takes 1000ms to serve a 304 on a small js file.

**Update 2:** `.git/objects/pack` is 104MB in the slow repo and the directory has tons of loose files in in even after running a `git gc` The newly cloned repo has 20MB `pack` folder and no loose objects.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly a red herring.

A git branch is literally nothing more than a 41 byte file in `.git/refs/heads` and I don't see any possible way that the mere existence of that file would cause this problem.

The asset pipeline doesn't know anything at all about whether or not your project uses git so it's not doing any git operations behind the scenes.

Try duplicating the original git repo and removing all the branches to see if that actually changes the performance.